# FB SDK 3.0 Do I need to extend access token or is it automatic?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, token

Based on http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/  Exception (Section) 3: If I use the "newer" SDK, it'll save the access token for me and will extend it automatically.

My questions:

[1] When it says "newer" SDK - does anyone knows whether this is referring to 3.0?

[2] Is there a way to manually assign FBSession an access token? FBSession's accessToken property is read-only.  My situation: in my app user logs in using their email address, and on my server the email address is linked to a facebook access token. Now if user logs in to my app in another device, my server will return FB access token in auth response; I would like FBSession to be assigned this same access token so they don't have to reauthenticate FB and hope the access token extending process is just happening magically.

Comment: After back and forth with Facebook support team, here's the answer:
[1] Yes. Facebook SDK doc is pathetic (unfortunately), it's not clear on the website but hey that's what we have to work with.
[2] Officially there is no way to do this. However answer from just.jimmy below contains a link to the github project, I can modify FBSession myself and assign the accessToken n stuff.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you don't have to worry about anymore. Looking at the code, FBSession takes care of extending the token & expiry date.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBSession.m

Comment: So are the default access tokens given now extended tokens lasting 60 days?

Comment: Yes "After the offline_access removal date (see roadmap for exact date), all existing offline_access access_tokens will have their expiration time truncated to 60 days."

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Hm interesting I didn't realize it's open source. I think I can just assign the accessToken myself by extending/modifying FBSession. Thanks for giving the link!